# Maven Tests not Running in sequential Order

Tags: maven, testng, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin, testng.xml

I'm using a TestNG framework for my automation project.

While running from command line i'm giving the following command.

mvn clean test -Dtest=Login,OpenImage,Logout

By running the above command it the order of execution was Login->Logout->OpenImage (may be in alphabetical order).

Can anyone help me how to run tests in the given order.

Note: As per my requirement I need to run my tests in the above way it self.
If it was through testNG.xml file then i guess preserve-order will work.

can anyone help me on this.....!!!!!
Thank you in advance..

Comment: First why do you need to run tests in a particula order because units should never rely on a particular order... If you need to run in order defined dependencies between the tests (`@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "serverStartedOk" })`)... Or you could use JUnit Jupiter which supports an order annotation...

Comment: TestNG allows to organize tests using suites (xml files) - that is what you actually need.

Comment: It most of the time easier to use dependsOnGroups etc. in combination with dependsOnMethods than manually mantain test suites...

Comment: BTW: What I missed you should use maven-failsafe-plugin (responsible for integration tests) in such case because as already mentioned `mvn test` runs unit tests executed by maven-surefire-plugin...

Answer (score 1):

First why do you need to run tests in a particula order because units should never rely on a particular order. But your question looks like more an integration tests.

If you need to run in order defined dependencies between the tests

```
@Test
public void serverStartedOk() {}
 
@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "serverStartedOk" })
public void method1() {}
```

The above defines the order that `serverStartedOk` will run before `method1`..based on the `dependsOnMethods`...

Comment: > because units should never rely on a particular order - it is so wrong for e2e tests.

Comment: We are not talking about E2E tests.. here we are talking about IT's ... which are not unit test which are given by the usage of `mvn test` which will run surefire-plugin which is for unit tests...